# Searching for records in several tables using EF TPT

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees, table-per-type

I have a project with TPT inheritance mapping, now I need to add it a search functionality that will find records in several tables. That's what I currently have:

```
public abstract class Customer
{
    public int      Id      { get; set; }
    public string   Memo    { get; set; }
...
}

public class Person : Customer
{
    public string   GivenName   { get; set; }
    public string   Surname     { get; set; }
...
}
public class Company : Customer
{
    public string       Name     { get; set; }
...
}
```

I also have a unit of work with bunch of repositories, and I need to add the filtering functionality to several methods of `CustomerRepository`. Let's say I have a `Count` method with the following signature

```
public int Count(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> filter = null)
```

Now I need to get the quantity of customers whose `GiveName` or `Surname` contains `searchTerm` in case the customer is a `Person` or the same `searchTerm` in `Name` field in case it is a Company.

**TL;DR**
*How a view with a single, searchable, paged list of `Customers` (containing both `Person` and `Company` types) should be implemented? I mean in terms of method with signature like `public IHttpActionResult Get(string searchTerm, int pageSize, int pageNumber)`...*

That's what I tried:
I added to each of the classes a static method that would generate an `Expression` to search that specific class, that's how it looks for the `Person` class:

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Person, bool>> GetFilter(string searchTerm)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm))
    {
        return null;
    }
    var parameterExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person));
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });

    return System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.OrElse(
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "GivenName"),
                    method,
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(searchTerm, typeof(string))
                ),
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.PropertyOrField(parameterExpression, "Surname"),
                    method,
                    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(searchTerm, typeof(string))
                )
            ), parameterExpression);
}
```

And tried to build an `Expression` that would check the type of the customer and then make an appropriate data check, but here I stumped... That's what I have right now:

```
    var parameterExpression = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer));
    var typeIsPerson = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.TypeIs(parameterExpression, typeof(Person));
    var typeIsCompany = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.TypeIs(parameterExpression, typeof(Company));

    var q = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Block(
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.IfThen(typeIsPerson, Person.GetFilter(searchTerm)),
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.IfThen(typeIsCompany, Company.GetFilter(searchTerm)),
        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(false));

    var a = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(
            q, parameterExpression);
```

Here I have two problems(at least?), first when I try to call Count, I get a very unpleasant `NotSupportedException` exception that says `Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Block'`. The second is that I don't know how to return the result of execution for each of `GetFilters`, I suspect that I will get `false` for any record since it is default value that is the last `Expression` in my `Block`...
May be I'm on a wrong track and this is something that should be done in a completely different manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression blocks are generally unsupported in LINQ to Entities. And normally you don't need them because you could build almost any expression just using C# conditional operator `? :` (which maps to [`Expression.Condition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340500(v=vs.110).aspx)).

But before even trying to build an expression dynamically, you need to find a EF supported construct working with TPT (and other EF inheritance models) polymorphic query. Which is not so easy because all the examples use `OfType` method which is only applicable when you need to filter a concrete derived entities. With some trial and error, luckily there are two supported constructs - `is` and `as` (important: `as`, not cast!).

So the statically built predicate expression in question could be like this:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> predicate = c =>
    c is Person ? 
        ((c as Person).GivenName.Contains(searchTerm) || (c as Person).Surname.Contains(searchTerm)) :
    c is Company ? 
        (c as Company).Name.Contains(searchTerm) :
    false;
```

(Frankly you don't want to look at the generated SQL, but it works)

Now you can build it dynamically if you wish. You already found the `is` expression method ([`Expression.TypeIs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeis(v=vs.110).aspx)), for `as` operator the corresponding expression metod is [`Expression.TypeAs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.typeas(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your input, +1, I was investigating in this direction for the last few hours, will keep you updated...

Comment: Very well, I will mark your answer as accepted, but regardless, allow me to ask first - can you suggest any sources that you gained this knowledge from(I mean f.e. your statement that expression blocks are generally unsupported in LINQ to Entities)? or it's plain trial and error? And another thing is - can you suggest any other way of achieving the same functionality, if it is possible at all with TPT?

Comment: It really is by experimenting (if there was a source, I would have included a link in the answer). Although it's logical - the block expression tree can be used only in LINQ to Objects, because it's simply compiled to code and executed, while in LINQ to Entities it has to be translated to SQL, so it really needs to be an expression (you can't embed code blocks inside SQL). What about alternative way, that's the only supported expression I found. Eventually, since it's generating SQL `UNION` query anyway, you could use LINQ `Concat` with subqueries based on `OfType`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do all that. Just create a generic method that you will *close* when you call it. Your generic method can be like this:

```
public static int Count<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null)
{
    var ctx = new StackContext();
    return ctx.Customers.OfType<T>().Where(filter).Count();
}
```

You can call that like this:

```
// Here you are closing the generic to be of type Person
var personsCount = Count<Person>(x => x.GivenName == "George");
// Here you are closing the generic to be of type Customer
var companyCount = Count<Company>(x => x.Name == "Test");
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I believe I wasn't clear enough - I want to be able to search for records from both tables using a single query. When we discuss `Count` it's quite simple to add results from two queries, but how would I implement paging after filtering the set?

Comment: For paging you will use Skip and Take. For both tables, it will work too as long as you call it properly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your idea, I need to create a view that will show a list of customers regardless of their type, that is, both `Person` and `Company`, with a possibility to search and page, when you filter the set using `OfType<T>()` you get only one of the types - either `Person` or `Company`. How would you suggest to implement a view with a paged single list that contains both of them?